# Как при нажатии на кнопку на сайте заставить бота отправлять текст в телеграм?

Tags: python, html, telegram, бот, веб-сайт

Принцип работы таков: на сайте находится кнопка для "вызова сотрудника", когда человек на неё нажимает, бот в телеграм должен отправить сообщение о том, что поступил вызов с такой-то локации. Везде туторы на отправку формы, а нужна именно связь "нажаите кнопки -> текст из кода в чат"
(Сайт на html, тг-бот на python)

Comment: Как вариант: нажали кнопку, занесли информацию в БД. Бот чекает БД на наличие новых записей. Новая запись -> отправили сообщение. Да алгоритмов можно сколько угодно придумать)

Comment: Мой вариант, сделайте flask вместе с ботом, на flask сервер отсылайте post, обрабатывайте и отправляйте сообщение куда нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации твоей задумки, я думаю тебе поможет библиотека `flask`. Простыми словами, **Flask - это фреймворк** (набор инструментов и правил), который помогает создавать веб-приложения с использованием языка программирования Python. Flask делает процесс создания веб-сайтов более удобным, предоставляя готовые инструменты для обработки запросов от пользователей и отправки им ответов.
Если ты хочешь узнать побольше о `Flask`, то можешь почитать данную статью:`https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/chto-takoe-flask-i-kak-na-nem-bystro-napisat-prostoy-sayt`

1. Для начала надо импортировать необходимые модули:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram import Bot
```

2. Далее создаем объекты `Flask` и `Bot`, используя токен твоего бота:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
bot = Bot(token='YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')
```

3.Создаем маршрут, который будет обрабатывать нажатие кнопки на твоем сайте:

```py
@app.route('/button_click', methods=['POST'])
def handle_button_click():
    # Получите данные из запроса, например, текст сообщения
    message_text = request.form.get('message_text')

    # Отправьте сообщение в чат Telegram
    bot.send_message(chat_id='YOUR_CHAT_ID', text=message_text)

    return 'OK'
```

4. Осталось только запустить веб-сервер `Flask`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Все, с python покончено, осталось только создать кнопки, которые при нажатии отправляли запрос. Я напишу свой код, но ты можешь его изменить для своих нужд:

```html
<form action="http://your-server-address/button_click" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message_text" value="Текст для отправки в чат Telegram">
    <button type="submit">Вызвать сотрудника</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Будут ли работать команды в tg (через /) и  обработка текстового сообщения юзера в этом же самом коде? Или нужно создавать отдельный для обработки сообщений в чате и соединить его с этим?

Comment: @Лиза Да, в коде выше обработка команд в Telegram через `/` и обработка текстовых сообщений пользователя выполняется в одном коде.

Comment: перенесла часть скрипта на обработку сообщений в чате, но, когда запускаю программу, работает только то, что стоит выше другого(например: работает или скрипт сайта, или скрипт бота, сообща команды не исполняются). С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Лиза 
Возможно, проблема связана с тем, что у вас два разных сервиса (сайт и бот) пытаются использовать один и тот же порт для прослушивания запросов. Flask обычно по умолчанию работает на порту 5000.